# How to call a function in the matlab command window?

Tags: matlab, function

Suppose I have a matlab file called `add.m` with the code

```
function x = add(a, a)
    x = a + b
end
```

I'd like to be able to call this function from the matlab command window, but I get the error `Undefined function or variable 'add'.`, and when I try to copy and paste the function into the command window, I get the error that `Function definitions are not permitted in this context.`  How can I get around this?

Comment: You need to either change your working directory to the folder containing `add.m`, or add that folder to your path

Comment: Agree with [tmpearce](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1214731/tmpearce), add location of file to PATH